# one-sided binomial confidence interval using brute force on CDF rather than Clopper-Pearson/Wilson/etc

Tags: binomial-distribution

I was recently trying to solve a marketing problem. For say 300 trial users, only 3 converted to paying subscribers. The conversion rate for this sample is obviously 1%. And almost as obvious, we cannot be confidence that the actual (e.g. population) conversion rate is anything close to 1% with just 3 positives.

We are looking for a one-sided left tail test - what is the lower bound for conversion rates? We don't care if the actual is too high, only if it is too low.

The Central Limit Theorem is particularly bad in this case. At 95% confidence, the lower bound would be an impossible -0.63%... lower than the 0% lower bound for this Bernoulli process / binomial distribution. My understanding is that an imbalanced Bernoulli distribution is just so spikey, the CLT doesn't start to work until your sample size get larger.

I read about the Clopper-Pearson and Wilson test and they all look better suited to a time with limited computation. What's preventing me from doing a search on the binomial pdf, with n=300 and k=3, to find the value of p that delivers a 95 percentile of the distribution - in this case a p of 0.456%?

```py
>>> scipy.stats.binom.cdf(3, 300, 0.00456) 
0.950222823079971
```